# How to serialize result of objects.filter django based on foreign key object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models one with a foreign key to the other:

```
class Booking(models.Model):

type_course_requested = models.ManyToManyField(TypePost, blank=True)
    .....
    #Presentation Message

    message = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class BookingDemand(models.Model):

    booking = models.ForeignKey(Booking, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to get bookingdemands based on certain condition, and then serializing to have something like the code below:

```
{ 'booking1': { 'key1':...
               'bookingDemands': {....}
             }, 
  'booking2': {...}
}
```

Filtering is done like this:

```
bookings=BookingDemand.objects.filter(booking__post__person=self.request.user)
```

which returns a queryset, but I can't find how to serialize them to have each booking separatly as mentionned above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a serializer and set **`depth=1`** as below

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class BookingDemandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BookingDemand
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

then serialize your queryset as

```
bookings = BookingDemand.objects.filter(booking__post__person=self.request.user)
booking_serializer = BookingDemandSerializer(bookings, many=True)
booking_serializer.data  # here is the serialized data
```

**UPDATE**

```
# serializer.py
from rest_framework import serializers


class BookingDemandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BookingDemand
        fields = '__all__'


class BookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    booking_demands = BookingDemandSerializer(source='bookingdemand_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = '__all__'


# serialization process
queryset = Booking.objects.all()  # apply filter if you want
serializer = BookingSerializer(queryset, many=True)
serializer.data # here is the data
```

Comment: This creates a querydict containing each BookingDemand including the corresponding Father Booking. What I want is the opposite: Each booking with its corresponding BookingDemands. For e.g. If you have 1 Booking with 3 Demands, this gives 3 entries. I would like to have 1 entry of Booking that has 3 entries for each Demand.

Comment: Solved. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Create two serializers **BookingSerializer and BookingDemandSerializer** and add

```
booking(related_name) = BookingDemandSerializer(many=True) in BookingSerializer
```